# how to fill Map<Object,Object> from Flux<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>,use reactiveRedisTemplate

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
Flux<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entries = reactiveRedisTemplate .opsForHash().entries(key);
Map<Object, Object> stringObjectMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
entries.subscribe(e -> stringObjectMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

I want to fill `stringObjectMap` from entries,but `stringObjectMap` is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem a couple of days ago, and ended up using the `collectMap` operation. My use case required that I extract a Processor object from redis, which was stored as hashes, so for doing this, I found out that i can use the following :

```
operations.opsForHash().entries("processor") // Returns a list of Entry<String,String>
```

The list of entries will have to be collected as to a map, so that it can be mapped to an object, using the `ObjectMapper`. The following lambda chain extracts all the hashes from the "processor" key, maps them as a map using `collectMap` and then using the `.map()` function, converts this map into a Processor object.

```
        Mono<Processor> processor = operations.opsForHash()
                                        .entries("processor")
                                        .collectMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue)
                                        .map(entryMap -> new ObjectMapper().convertValue(entryMap, Processor.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you accounted for the fact that everything is asynchronous?

In this case, the `subscribe` method doesn't block until the map has been filled but instead returns control immediately. If your next line of code checks the map's content, it might simply be empty because the async operation hasn't completed yet.

Note that there is a `collectMap` operator that produces a `Map` reactively (and you can even provide a `Supplier<Map>` to force a `LinkedHashMap` instance). Here if you subscribe twice in a row, your map will be shared between the two subscriptions which will both attempt to fill it (which might lead to synchronization issues)...